# Wordpress - Show parent category AND subcategory name in subcategory URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I am create Custom Taxonomy for Custom Post Types all are set. But I want Show to also parent category with subcategory name in subcategory URL it means I am create Custom Taxonomy house_type than I am create 1bhk, 2bhk, Bungalow and so on . But then I am create 3bhk and his Parent home_type select to Bungalow and then after post then just check my link is look like to:

my url look like this

http://localhost/project/house/3bhk/my-houses ‎

But I want to add also Parent home_type in 3bhk select Bungalow and his final url this look like that:

http://localhost/project/house/Bungalow/3bhk/my-houses

What the changes required in my custom post type taxonomy to find this url. Please help.

Comment: looks very related to what you want https://gist.github.com/kasparsd/2924900

Comment: one more http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/

Comment: @cjmling i am use this  (gist.github.com/kasparsd/2924900) all code for example and put in my function.php but this code also didn't display to his parent category in url...it means  they show only Occasions Occasions parent category don't show in url............